# ExpanderView not showing controls inside it

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

In the below XAML, I am able to see the controls inside the expanderview on expanding which is on GridRow 6 but not able to see any controls inside the expanderview which is on GridRow 0. Can anyone help me as to what am I missing here?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,50,0,1" Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="0"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image x:Name="img1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,92,0,0" Source="Images/1.png" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.ZIndex="3"></Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbScore" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Width="Auto" Margin="-32,97,0,0" FontFamily="TypeFace" FontSize="18" Canvas.ZIndex="3"/>
                    <Image x:Name="img1" Height="90" Margin="-23,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Width="Auto" Margin="27,20,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="22" Tap="tbUserName_Tap"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF747171" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,10,0,0" FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="20" Tap="tbScreenName_Tap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="evMoreDetails" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Collapsed="evMoreDetails_Collapsed" Header="V  " Foreground="Black" FontSize="26" Expanded="evMoreDetails_Expanded">
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" x:Name="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,8,0,0" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding name}" />
                                    <TextBlock  Width="Auto" x:Name="Name1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,2,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding name1}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="6" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="evMore" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,0,50" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                <TextBlock Text="+    more" FontSize="26" Foreground="Black">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lb" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Width}">
                                        <Image x:Name="ProfilePic" Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding image}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Width}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <TextBlock Width="Auto" x:Name="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,8,0,0" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding name}" />
                                                <TextBlock  Width="Auto" x:Name="Name1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,2,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding name1}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelect" IsChecked="{Binding isprim}" Foreground="Black" Tag="{Binding id}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView>
            </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem in past. Please specify some height for expander item, in your case give some height to stackpanel at row 0.